# Ajax issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I'm counting clicks on a link by calling a page with AJAX but in Firefox, apparently because the page called is never actually loaded, for some reason Firefox never calls it. It seems like the link is clicked and then Firefox makes the AJAX call but somehow because the page changes to the actual link in the href then the AJAX call is never actually sent (appears red in firebug and no sign of it in Fiddler). It works fine in IE & Chrome and if I change the link to target="_new" then it will work in Firefox. Am I making some sort of stupid mistake?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript">
function adtrk(cde){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    var r=Math.random();
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaresp = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/atr.php?cde=" + cde + "&r=" + r, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<a onclick="adtrk('zip1'); return true;" href="http://www.google.com"><img src="/images/img.jpg"></a>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Why do you have `return true;` in your click handler?  That will make the browser follow the link, thus killing your AJAX request.  Change that to `return false;`, and the redirect in the callback.

Comment: @RocketHazmat but then the user never gets to actually go to that page. This stops the unload, and makes it so the count request goes through, but it also breaks the link.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: You can redirect them to the link in the AJAX callback :)

Comment: You could do that but it's not very nice UX.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: True, that does sound like it may be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page changes before the ajax request is done. You should wait for you ajax request to end before changing page by running it synchronously :

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/atr.php?cde=" + cde + "&r=" + r, false);
```

Comment: This answer fixed it. Does this mean that the browser will not move to the oage in the href until this call is finished?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes exactly, thé browser will wait

Answer (score 4):

When you load a new page any open AJAX requests will be cancelled (by the browser). Your server probably never sees the click count request.

Either always open links in a new window or use some other mechanism for counting clicks, like a proxy/redirect.

Comment: I was using redirects before but they were drowned out by bots, this was really the only other way I could think of to get some sort of accurate click count.